# How can I attach field names to to their value in a separate table in ms access?

Tags: ms-access

For example:

Fields A1 to A4 has these values in table1

```
A1|A2|A3|A4
 1| 3| 5| 6
```

I need to make it into table2 as

```
Field | Value
A1    | 1
A2    | 3
A3    | 5
A4    | 6
```

i hope i can get an answer soon. Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't understand the point of table1. Why would you only have one record in the table? Why do you need to make table2? Could you give more detail into what you are trying to accomplish from start to end?

Comment: sorry i just given one set of data, i have thousands, its a reading from a data logger

Comment: were trying to get the total valid data per instrument, i hope you can help with a clear sample. thank you for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some VBA code to do this:

```vb
sub StoreTransposedData()
    dim db as DAO.Database, rsIn as DAO.Recordset, rsOut as DAO.Recordset
    dim field as String, val as Integer
    dim j as Integer
    set db = currentdb()
    set rsIn = db.openRecordset("YourInputTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    set rsOut = db.openRecordset("YourOutputTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbEdditAdd)
    with rsIn
        .moveFirst
        do
            for j = 0 to .Fields.Count - 1
                field = .Fields(j).Name
                val = .Fields(j).Value
                with rsOut
                    .addNew
                        .Fields("field").value = field
                        .Fields("value").value = val
                    .update
                end with
            next j
            .moveNext
        loop until .EOF
        .close
    end with
    rsOut.close
    db.close
end sub
```

Honestly, I don't see any reason for you to want/need this... but this is a possible solution.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, thanks for the code it worked perfectly with my code, i have another question, maybe you can just update your script... i forgot to include that a date field on table 1 and each record in table 2 should have it per line as a grouping variable... therefore there will be 3 fields in table 2... date, field, and value. I hope you can help me on this... thanks

Comment: I think you can try to solve that by yourself: simply edit the code. You need to understand what the code does.... Once you've done that, the edit you need to do to the code is really little

Comment: Hi, can you help me do the same if the file is an excel? thanks

Comment: @WolVerine before asking, you should [try to solve it yourself](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Also, I remind you that comments are not the place to ask for questions.

Comment: hi sir, thank you. i posted the code i am working now with to accomplish the same outcome with the date field as an identifier, but i can only read one line of the csv file... i hope you can help me... thanks

Comment: @WolVerine If you have a *new* question, please use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include your attempted solution.